# Prim's Algorithm for Minimum Weight Spanning Tree

Tags: graph-theory

[image: Problem from Textbook]

I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong in using Prim's Algorithm, here's what I have:

- Start at $a, (a,d),(a,e),(d,i),(i,b),(b,f),(f,k)$

This seems to be going well but in my tree $a$ and $f$ already have degree $2$ so how would I connect $L$ to this graph? Don't I need to have every vertice in my tree and also have every vertice of degree $\le 2$?

Comment: Vertices in a minimum spanning tree can have more than 2 degree. Or else it is a chain, not a tree.

Comment: ah thank you for some reason I took the algorithm to imply that each vertex can only have degree 2, thank you!